# asp.net ffmpeg: The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: c#, asp.net, ffmpeg

I am doing code for extracting image from video using ffmpeg. But gone stuck what this means. I also have checked

```
ffmpeg -i F:\MIC\stream\finalstream\casper\small.mp4  -an -ss 00:00:03 -s 108*80 -vframes 1 -f image2 -vcodec mjpeg F:/MIC/stream/finalstream/caspe
r/output11.png
```

on cmd line and working fine but dont understand why this is not happening in asp.net?

here is my code this function happens on button click event:

```
protected void Capture(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            string InputFile = @"F:\MIC\stream\finalstream\casper\small.mp4";
            string ThumbnailsPath = @"F:\MIC\stream\finalstream\casper\testimage.jpg";
            System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            proc.EnableRaisingEvents = false;
            proc.StartInfo.FileName = Page.MapPath("~/ffmpeg.exe");
            proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "-i F:/MIC/stream/finalstream/casper/small.mp4  -an -ss 00:00:03 -s 108*80 -vframes 1 -f image2 -vcodec mjpeg F:/MIC/stream/finalstream/casper/ output11.png";
            proc.Start();


        }
```

while running i got this Error:
[image]

Any idea????

Comment: According to your command line test, you could remove `ffmpeg` from `StartInfo.Arguments`, and try `Server.MapPath("~/ffmpeg.exe")` for the file path of the executable. I also notice that you use forward slashes in the code where you use backslashes in your command line test.

Comment: Why did you specify `-f mjpeg` but output a png?

Comment: sorry for late reply. I have to go to hospital for my bro. i placed 
Server.MapPath("~/ffmpeg.exe") and gives same error i am getting. Like u said i shd be using backslah but compiler gives me escape sequence error.

Comment: i did  changes according to ConnorsFan suggestions. plz have a look.  even  debug is not helping  me.

Comment: did you find any solutions, I'm currently facing the same issue, directory exists but it isnt working in python with ffmpeg